# How to change to color of a point in JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm making a program that needs to plot graphs with many different colors and shades .

More specifically, I'm using a scatter graph, and for each new point it has to be in a darker shade than the previously one. When the color of the point became near black, I change the color too.

I tried to do this extending `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` and then the method `getItemColor`.

It successfully changed the color and shape of the points (using `Color.getHSBColor` method), but it didn't change in the sequence I expepected. I thought it would change the color in the sequence the points were inserted, but instead of this, it changed like if the graph was already plotted, and the colors became sequential.

But it's a scatter plot, so I expected a mixture of colors and shapes. So, is it possible to change the color of a point, while this point is being plotted in the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you are using [XYSeriesCollection](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeriesCollection.html) for your dataset.  Read carefully the description for the XYSeries [constructor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#XYSeries%28java.lang.Comparable%29)...you probably dont want the default `autoSort` behavior for the series.